# Objects & Inheritance

Tags: java, object, data-structures

I'm very new to programming and have an assignment to create a simple Pizza ordering program. It should make use of objects and utilize inheritance. For the first part of the assignment I have to create:

1) pizzaBase class - models a pizza base (thick or thin)

2) pizzaTopping class - models a pizza topping

3) Pizza class - carry essential information about a pizza, including a single base and multiple toppings

What is the best way to create and store the topping and base objects? and how would I implement inheritance into this program? Later on I have to create a user interface to take orders using the topping and base objects and to also check the pizza to see if it is suitable for vegetarians.

Here is some code I have so far:

```
public class Pizza  {

    private PizzaBase base;
    private ArrayList<PizzaToppings> topList;

    public Pizza(PizzaBase b){
        this.setBase(b);
        this.topList = new ArrayList<PizzaToppings>();
    }

    public void setBase(PizzaBase b){
        base = b;
    }

    public void addTop(PizzaToppings topping){
        topList.add(topping);
    }

    public double pizzaCost(){  
        double cost = base.getcost();
        for(PizzaToppings topping : topList)
        {
            cost += topping.getTopCost();
        }
        return cost;
    }

    public void OrderSummary()
    {

        System.out.println(base.getBase() + ": \t" + base.getcost());
        for(PizzaToppings topping : topList)
        {
            System.out.println(topping.getTopName() + ": " + topping.getTopCost());
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("total: "+ pizzaCost());
    }
```

}

```
public class PizzaBase {

    private String baseName;
    private double cost;

    public PizzaBase(String base, double cost) {
        this.baseName = base;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getBase() {
        return baseName;
    }

    public double getcost() {
        return cost;
    }

}
```

Comment: My experience with this excercise (and others in that book) is that the actual scope of work does not at all motivate the design the book puts forward. This is a common ailment of books on programming which try to explain concepts used (and *useful*) in codebases above 10,000 lines of code, on examples with 100 lines of code.

Comment: Marko, do you know of any solutions to this ailment? (I'm not asking this in a sarcastic way, but a genuinely interested way. I agree it's a problem.)

Answer (score 0):

The Pizza class could extend the PizzaBase class with additional methods, such as addTopping(). There's a hint in the name - PizzaBase could be seen as a base class.

In real life, I wouldn't use inheritance here. I'd have a Pizza class that is constructed with a PizzaBase and some toppings (i.e. basically what you've done).

I'd rename PizzaToppings as PizzaTopping since it only represents one topping. For the vegetarian checking, you'd need each topping to know if it was suitable for vegetarians. Then in Pizza you can iterate over all the toppings and return false if any topping is not suitable or true if all the toppings are suitable.

More style hints:

- Rename pizzaCost() as cost() - it's on the Pizza class, so we know that it's the cost of the Pizza. Ditto for getTopCost(). It can be cost() instead.
- Declare your field as a List<> rather than an ArrayList<> (you still need to construct an ArrayList but the field type doesn't need to be so specific)
- Rename topList as toppings
- Put your opening braces on the ends of the line before, not a new line. This is the most widely adopted coding convention for Java.
- Don't capitalize methods (e.g. OrderSummary should be orderSummary). In that method, I'd return a String, rather than printing to stdout. Leave it to the caller to print if it wants to.
- Use camelCase for methods (e.g. getcost should be getCost or even better: cost()).

If you extend PizzaBase...

```
public class Pizza extends PizzaBase {

    // ...

    public double cost() {
        double cost = super.cost();
        for (PizzaTopping topping: toppings) {
            cost += topping.cost();
        }
        return cost;
    }
}
```

I wouldn't bother precalculating the cost as Arden suggests. In my view that would be premature optimization and only saves cycles if the caller keeps calling cost().

I would beware of using doubles to represent financial amounts. Use BigDecimal instead to avoid rounding errors. Also, is it a cost or a price? Need to be very accurate with words.